# Solution for backup webserver by ubuntu and mysql?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, webserver, backup, lamp

We had a webserver on Ubuntu14.04 server that was implemeted by LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) and phpMyAdmin to manage database.

Now we will buy one more server for backup our webserver. However, I don't know the solution for this work. I heard about some solution like loadbalancing, cron, mysqldumb, Master Slave Replication... but I don't know which solution suitable with us and how to implement it.

I need a solution for this problem when the web server 1 is disrupted, our system will redirect to web server 2 (server backup) and work well without missing data.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

**Master/slave :**

Master/slave if your stuff (CMS, etc...) can consider read-only mode of slave to be used.
It's better if your stuff handle master/slave replication in configuration (= is not trying to send UPDATE or DELETE to a slave server which will give errors)
Slave server can also be use as a SELECT server to help DB handling more request.. 
You don't need anything else but MySQL and 2 servers to do that. You'll find many help on internet about how to install [master/slave](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql).

**Master/master :**

Problem with master/slave replication is that slave server will be accessible in read-only mode only. Most tools (CMS or whatever) require writing DB even when consulting for whatever reason (Session handling etc..)
Master/master replication is probably the best choice , but you'll need a third party : have a look at [MMM](http://mysql-mmm.org/) and its [installation guide](http://mysql-mmm.org/mmm2:guide).